# Is it possible to restrain access to a LocalStorage item to only a specific path url?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, local-storage

Let’s say I have a website :
https://website.com

This website has two pages :
https://website.com/page1
https://website.com/page2

On the page1, I have some JavaScript writing and reading data in the the LocalStorage, let’s say ["myKey" => "myValue"].

Is there a way to restrain access to "myKey" to only page1, so that page2 or any other page on this website can’t read nor write this data ? Maybe a parameter when calling localStorage.setItem() ?

(I know that localStorage data access is scoped on the website, so by default in this scenario "page2" has access to it, but this is what I want to prevent)

I looked online but nobody seemed to have encountered this problem.

Comment: Given they're same domain these pages are supposed to trust each other. Aren't you the author of the scripts that run in both pages? Can't you simply avoid writing from there? What are you trying to protect against?

Comment: @Kaiido in my scenario I cannot trust the other page. It might be an uploaded file for instance

Comment: How come they run on the same domain then? You should sandbox it if you don't trust it, otherwise it will be able to run anything from page1 as if it was page1, not just read the localStorage.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: I know in my scenario the problem comes from the design, and uploaded files should be sandboxed. But my question was more because I was curious than to actually solve my situation, But thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to restrict access to a specific key in LocalStorage to only one page on a website.

One solution to this problem would be to use a different key for each page. You could, for example, use a prefix for each key that corresponds to the page where it is being used, such as "page1_myKey" and "page2_myKey". This way, you could easily identify which keys belong to which page, and you could check the prefix before accessing the key's value.